# Calculating the upper bound of a function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I was studying *Existence and uniqueness theorem* from [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_9tWJ0r3XAhUNUI8KHbdYAvkQFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.iitk.ac.in%2F~sghorai%2FTEACHING%2FMTH203%2Fode5.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2CKpCh4cn-bzQ-90bQ4I2l). Now I got the following question.

> Test the uniqueness of the initial value problem $(x-2y+1)dy - (3x-6y+2)dx = 0; y(0) = 0$
>    over the rectangle $|x| \le 1/4 ; |y| \le 1/4$
>   . Determine the interval for $x$ over which the solution is
>   guaranteed.

Now from the theorem 1, I have to show that $|f(x,y)| \le K \text{   } \forall (x,y) \in R$,i.e.,

$$ \left| \frac{3x-6y+2}{x-2y+1} \right| \le K \text{   } \forall (x,y) \in R$$
where, 
$$R = \{(x, y) : |x − x_0 | ≤ 1/4, |y − y_0| ≤ 1/4\}, (a, b > 0).
$$
So, my question is how to calculate the upper bound of the function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find AN upper bound (not the minimal one) note that for all $(x,y)\in R=[-1/4,1/4]^2$,
$$\begin{align}\left| \frac{3x-6y+2}{x-2y+1} \right| &\leq \frac{\max_R|3x-6y+2|}{\min_R|x-2y+1|}\\&\leq \frac{2+3\max_R|x|+6\max_R|y|}{1-\max_R|x|-2\max_R|y|}\\&\leq \frac{2+3/4+6/4}{1-1/4-2/4}=17.
\end{align}$$
P.S. Note that $|f|$ is continuous in the compact set $R$ ($f$ is a rational function such that its denominator is never zero in $R$). Therefore $|f|$ is bounded in $R$.

Comment: To minimize the denominator why have to taken maximum of x and y ?

Comment: Note that $|x−2y+1|\geq 1-|x|-2|y| \geq 1-\max_R|x|-2\max_R|y|$. Use the triangle inequality!